# Is AGSDynamicMapServiceLayer Class removed from ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS 100.4 Swift, or is it replaced with another class?

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

Is AGSDynamicMapServiceLayer Class removed from ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS 100.4 Swift, or is it replaced with another class? It's not included in the latest api-reference
https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/

Comment: I'm trying to update my project from version 10.2.5, but I didn't find the classes I'm using in the new SDK reference, and I didn't find any reference of a replacement or if it's deprecated, I'll be thankful for any hint.